# .tolowercase() only text except URL's?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been working on this script for Greasemonkey. Problem is .tolowercase() obviously it's making anything uppercase to lowercase, which breaks URL's. I've looked into .startswith() and .endswith() as possible solutions, such as starts with http and https; maybe prefix detection some how 'http*'? Anyways, this is the code below, thanks in advance:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        twitter intent
// @namespace   random
// @description twitter intent popupwindow text replace
// @include     https://twitter.com/intent/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==


$('#status').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(text.toLowerCase()
        .replace('... ', ' ... ')
        .replace('health ', '#health ')
        .replace('video', 'Video')
        .replace('emergency', '#emergency')
        .replace('climate change', '#climatechange')
        .replace('climate ', '#climate ')
    );      
});
```

This is the HTML before the code is ran on it.

```
<textarea id="status" name="status" required="" autofocus="" aria-required="true" aria-describedby="post-error char-count">EPA shuts down program helping states adjust to climate change http://hill.cm/FH2iWpq</textarea>
```

edit: its important that the text except urls is to have upper or lower case ignored yet still .replace text if the words them selves are detected.

Comment: So, you want urls to stay as it is?

Comment: you are correct

Comment: `$('#status').each(` doesn't make sense since ID's must be unique by definition. Also are url's in text or in `<a>` tags? Provide a [mcve]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show some example inputs and the required output. What is the actual content of your `'#status'` field? (Show the HTML.)

Comment: Thanks. That seems an odd string to want to change to lowercase, given that (other than the URL) the only part that isn't already lowercase is "EPA", which would normally be uppercase, but at least it makes the question fairly clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I've tried with a combination of stocking the position, the url and re-appending it.

This end up like this :

```js
$('#status').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    var n = text.indexOf('http');
    var url = text.match('http(s?):\/\/[^<\s]*');
    if(url){
        text = text.replace(url[0],'')
    }
    text = text.toLowerCase()
        .replace('... ', ' ... ')
        .replace('health ', '#health ')
        .replace('video', 'Video')
        .replace('emergency', '#emergency')
        .replace('climate change', '#climatechange')
        .replace('climate ', '#climate ')
    if(url){
        text = text.slice(0,n) + url[0] + text.slice(n);
    }
    $(this).text(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="status" name="status" required="" autofocus="" aria-required="true" aria-describedby="post-error char-count">EPA shuts down program helping states adjust to climate change http://hill.cm/FH2iWpq</textarea>
```

Comment: thanks to everyone and their efforts, but this answer fits and works best, i look forward to everyone's replies benefiting someone other than me

Comment: im getting a weird issue how ever, when using `.replace('climate change', '#climatechange')` it removed the space beween #climatechange and link

Comment: I modified `var url = text.match(' http(s?):\/\/[^<\s]*');` and seems to work, but I don't know if it's the best solution; i added a space in front of http.

Comment: problem, this needs to work even if no URL is listed or shown

Comment: I've edited it for it to work even without url.
For the extra space your solution work even If I would advise to add it in the last if like `...+' '+url[0]+...`

Answer (score 1):

Try parsing your text to URL, and if it works, don't lower-case it:

You can see it works in a fiddle I made - https://jsfiddle.net/y1jh5w0w/.

```
text = text.split(' ');

text.forEach(function (value, index) {
    try {
        var url = new URL(value);
    } catch (ex) {
        text[index] = value.toLowerCase();
    }
});

text = text.join(' ');
```

Comment: OK, try this please.

Comment: im looking to replace multiple words as mentioned above, not a specific sentence, if that is what you're implying

Comment: may i add its important to ignore text whether it is upper or lower case, and only ignore URLS

Comment: I'm not implying that, I took your sentence as an example.
And currently my code will lower-case all the words that are not a URL inside a sentence, you can change the example text and test it.

Comment: here is also a bit of code from something entirely different, maybe, it can be modified some how https://jsfiddle.net/7hkg7c8z/

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use regex to find if some string is starting from `https://` or `http://`, then don't apply `toLowerCase` on it.

```js
const regex = /^(https:\/\/)/g;
const str = `https://www.FaceBook.com`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

So, you can create a function to check if string is URL and then execute `toLowerCase` on non-URL strings.

Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

**Updated after OP showed some snippet**

I still believe regex is the solution for you

Here's the updated snippet

```js
var str = 'EPA shuts down program helping states adjust to climate change http://hill.cm/FH2iWpq  Which url is lowercased dummy text';
var regex = /^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/g;
str.split(" ").forEach(function (obj) {
  if(obj.match(regex) === null) {
    obj = obj.toLowerCase();
  }
  console.log(obj);
})
```

As you can see, everything's got lowercased except URL.

Comment: i am trying to get it to work, but im not having any luck

Comment: ive added this below my code, in conjunction with .tolowercase() in my code, seems to work.

Comment: may i add its important to ignore text whether it is upper or lower case, and only ignore URLS, meaning regaurdless if text is uppercase or lower, the text itself should just be detected and replaced if said so.

Comment: here is also a bit of code from something entirely different, maybe, it can be modified some how https://jsfiddle.net/7hkg7c8z/

Answer (score 0):

```
var dictionary1= {
    " A":" b",
    " B":" b",
    " C":" C",
};

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
$("#status").each( function(){
    for( var ptrn in dictionary1){
        $(this).text( $(this).text().replace(new RegExp(ptrn ,"g"), dictionary1[ptrn] ) );
    }
});
}, 100);
});
```