# jQuery?: (.tolowercase .replace text.match) not working when URL isn't available

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on this greasemonkey script that works, except when no URL is present. It's to make everything lowercase except URL's, then replace what is requested to be. However, this needs to work, even if no URL is present within the DIV, im really not sure why it's behaving like this.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        twitter intent
// @namespace   covert
// @description twitter intent popupwindow text replace
// @include     https://twitter.com/intent/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==



$('#status').each(function() {
var text = $(this).text();
var n = text.indexOf('http');
var url = text.match(' http(s?):\/\/[^<\s]*');
text = text.replace(url[0],'');
text = text.toLowerCase()
.replace('climate change', '#climatechange')
.replace('climate ', '#climate ')
.replace('planet', '#planet')
.replace('ocean', '#ocean')
.replace('epa ', '#epa ')
text = text.slice(0,n) + url[0] + text.slice(n);
$(this).text(text);
});
```

Here is a working Fiddle. Just remove the URL in the HTML box, and all begins to stop working: **https://jsfiddle.net/qvsasvp2/**

---

*- This code is taken from: [.tolowercase() only text except URL's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43303603/)*

Comment: Time to learn to look at errors thrown in browser console for starters. Will give you reason for  *"begins to stop working"*

Comment: What URL are you talking about ?

Comment: @DanPhilip in the html content of demo

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `|| ''` to the line with the regular expression:

```
var url = text.match(' http(s?):\/\/[^<\s]*') || '';
```

This makes sure if there is no matching URL in the string (result is falsy, i.e. `null`), an empty string is assigned to `url`.

See updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w7ocbhcd/1/

Comment: Alway glad to help  don't forget to accept my answer

Comment: could you elaborate? what weird issues? what error messages? it works fine on my browser